# Java Program not locating all keywords while using LIKE SQL statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm building an application, and I'm trying to use PreparedStatements in order to execute SQL queries. Basically, there is a search option and I'm trying to use SQL LIKE method in the search box. The name is taken from the search box and is inserted into the PreparedStatement.

```java
try {

    PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_name LIKE ? AND status=?");
    ps2.setString(1, name2 + "%");
    ps2.setString(2, stat);
    ResultSet rs = ps2.executeQuery();

    dt.setRowCount(0);
    while (rs.next()) {
        Object ob[] = {
            rs.getString("book_name"),
            rs.getString("book_author")
        };
        dt.addRow(ob);
    }

} catch (Exception af) {
    jLabel29.setText("No result Found !");

}
break;
```

Where name2 is the what the user searches. However, when I do this, the program is only giving an output if the first word in the column "book_name" matches the searched item. For example, for a sentence "My name is Jack", if I type in "Jack" or "name", there is no output, but if I type in "My", the whole row is detected.

Comment: `LIKE 'xyz%'` means "starts with `xyz`". The `%` acts as a wildcard. So `LIKE '%xyz%'` would match anything containing `xyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `LIKE '%<searchString>%'` to consider all the preceeding and succeeding characters for wildcard search.

In other words, use:

```java
ps2.setString(1, "%" + name2 + "%");
```

Comment: Should I enter this in the PreparedStatement or the pst.setString ?

Comment: ps2.setString(1, name2 + "%"); becomes ps2.setString(1, "%" + name2 + "%");

Comment: Thank you so much Ravi and Mark for your help. I finally got it to work after sitting at it for quite some time xD